# Open PDF blob file in new browser tab with custom tile using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open the PDF file in the new tab using Javascript. And it is working fine except that the tab title. The tab title is showing some random GUID. I used the Browser Chrome.

**Code:**

```
var myBlob= new Blob([blob], {type: ‘application/pdf’})
var file = new File([myBlob], "fileName.pdf");
const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)
window.open(data)// it is opening the pdf in new tab but tab name is random GUID
```

So i have different approaches:

1. ```
   // it is opening the pdf in new tab but tab name is random GUID`
   window.open(data,"my custom tab name")
   ```
2. ```
   // still no luck`
   window.open(data,"my custom tab name").document.title = "New Page Title!";
   ```
3. ```
   // Still not working
   var newWindow = window.open(data,'_blank');  
   setTimeout(function () {
       newWindow.document.title = "My Tab Name";
   }, 100);
   ```
4. ```
   // still not working
   var newWindow = window.open(data, "_blank");
   newWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
       newWindow.document.title = 'New Title';
   });
   ```
5. ```
   // downloading file not showing in new tab
   var a = document.createElement('A');
   a.href = data;
   a.download = data;
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   a.click();
   document.body.removeChild(a);
   ```

So used all the approaches. I am able show the PDF in new tab, but i couldn't set the tab title.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works:

```
const newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.title = 'My Tab Name';
newWindow.document.write(`<style>body {margin: 0 !important;}</style><iframe src="${URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)}" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>`)
```

Comment: This is amazing, I also added some style before the iframe to remove the thick ugly borders of new tabs: `<style>body {margin: 0 !important;}</style>`

Comment: parenthesis missing after "newWindow.document.write" on third line

Answer (score 1):

The following code should display the PDF in the browser, while setting the tab title to something you provide.

```
var myBlob= new Blob([blob], {type: ‘application/pdf’})
const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);    

const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = fileUrl;
iframe.width = '100%';
iframe.height = '100%';
iframe.style.border = 'none';

const newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
newWindow.document.title = 'My Custom Title';  // alternatively 'filename.pdf'
```